# Selenium Click issue

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

The last line in the code below doesn't do the click.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\SohaibWaseem\PycharmProjects\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
user_name = driver.find_element_by_name("email") ###... checking user name or email box is available in page
print(user_name.is_displayed())      ### ... return true false of the status
print(user_name.is_enabled())        ### ... return true false of the status
pass_word = driver.find_element_by_name("pass")
print(pass_word.is_displayed())      ### ... return true false of the status
print(pass_word.is_enabled())        ### ... return true false of the status
user_name.send_keys("asdf")
pass_word.send_keys("asdf")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("Log In").click()
```

Comment: "Log In" is not an Xpath ... Also tag pycharm doesnt matter with your problem

Answer (score 1):

The xpath for Login button that you are targeting should be `//input[@id="u_0_b"]` not `Log In`
Now your last line in above code will look like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id="u_0_b"]").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

`Xpath` you are using for login button click, not looking like an xpath. `ID` is `dynamic` for login button and same `ID` format used for other `inputs field` on page so `partial ID match` will not work.

you can use `CSS` or `Xpath` with help of `data-testid` attribute.

**CSS**

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[data-testid='royal_login_button']").click()
```

**Xpath**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-testid='royal_login_button']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much,, now i have another error selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

'''
    from selenium import webdriver

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Sohaib 
Waseem\PycharmProjects\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

user_name = driver.find_element_by_name("email") 
print(user_name.is_displayed())     
print(user_name.is_enabled())        

pass_word = driver.find_element_by_name("pass")
print(pass_word.is_displayed())      
print(pass_word.is_enabled())        

user_name.send_keys("asdf")
pass_word.send_keys("asdf")

driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click()

time.sleep(2)

driver.back()
user_name.send_keys("my.email@gmail.com")
pass_word.send_keys("My password")

driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click()
```

'''

I have tried alot for exception but no result